# Run VSCode with different proxy configurations for various users

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have three machines:

- Personal
- Corporate with low restrictions
- Corporate with high restrictions

Because this I run my VSCode according to the machine I'm using. I thought profiles would store all different configurations, but the proxy seems to be global.

Is there a way to set the proxy configuration accordingly to the profile or machine? Only the computer with high proxy needs has this issue.

Every day, I have to manually remove or add the proxy configuration to start working.

The documentation says nothing about it, only that VSCode doesn't support this natively.

I searched for an add-on but found none.

Using profiles, I thought all my configurations would be stored, making each one a different version of my VSCode config. I was expecting that because the themes and some plugins are shown accordingly to the profile I'm using.